# Airflow upgrade 1.10.14 failed and cannot rollback to previous version which has the 1.10.10

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I upgraded docker image to use airflow 1.10.14. Airflow is deployed with helm and I have an init-container which execute script to initialize airflow. The init script contain commands

```
... 
airflow upgradedb
alembic upgrade heads
...
```

The upgrade failed so I need to rollback to previous deployed release version which contains the 1.10.10 version of airflow but it is now getting the alembic error. I tried to delete the row/record in the alembic_version table based on my search.

The error in scheduler container is this:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.DuplicateColumn) column "operator" of relation "task_instance" already exists
```

All the other pods are running fine (webserver and workers).

Any resolution/workaround to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are ok with scrapping your entire metadata DB (connections, variables, task runs, etc) I might opt to just push to 1.10.15 and see if the bug you encountered is resolved there. From my best understanding it is not possible to downgrade the DB after the upgrade has been done.

Suggesting upgrade to 1.10.15 based on if you remember encountering an issue similar to this user [here](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/13205#issue-771761423). The CLI fix can be [found here](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/13267). If you found another issue with your 1.10.14 upgrade besides the one I noted for the CLI, it might be worth investigating a path to resolving that instead.

Comment: I don't see 1.10.15 in airflow website. Is that an official release?

Comment: [1.10.15rc1](https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow/1.10.15rc1/) is available. Technically, it's pre-release but if it works, it works. See it tagged [here](https://github.com/apache/airflow/releases/tag/1.10.15rc1)

Comment: I noticed that beginning March 15, the 1.10.10 docker build  was pulling the sqlalchemy version 1.4. Before that it was pulling version 1.3. I have to override that version with pip install after installing the airflow. That fix the problem.